# Where can I find an explanation for this sorted() syntax?

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I'm doing a hackerrank problem which requires finding the top three occurrences of characters in a string ordered from most to least. If the count is the same then the characters should appear in alphabetical order. The input string given is 'aabbbccde' and result should be:
b 3
a 2
c 2
I don't understand how the following lambda function works. It's the right answer, and I know it returns a tuple with the second value first, but where can I find documentation on this particular syntax using -x to get descending order? I was able to research my version of sorted(), and it worked for three of the test cases, but not all. I haven't found any explanation on the first version, which is not my own work.

Sorting with this syntax solved all tests, some of which are hidden, but I don't understand the syntax:
`logo = sorted(all_freq.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`

This was my answer which solved some of the tests, including the sample given, but not all. I am assuming that the secondary alphabetical order isn't happening on all test cases using my version:
`logo = sorted(all_freq.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: I suppose I should back up a bit.  Do you not know what the `key=` argument does?  Do you not know what `lambda` means?

Comment: As for the logic of -x reversing - its not python syntax, just math. For example, negate the largest value and you get the smallest value.

Comment: you're right that the secondary alphabetical order isn't happening with *`key=lambda x:x[1]`*; that's because you've not included `x[0]` in the `key` which the function uses to sort by. Using `-x[1]` is the same as using `x[1]` with `reverse=True`, and using *`key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`* is like using **`sorted(sorted(all_freq.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`**. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#operator-module-functions) for more details

Comment: Thanks tdelaney! I thought it was some kind of pythony short cut, but simply negating the value so the sort remains ascending never occurred to me!

Answer (score 0):

lambda is a way to define a function locally.  For the sorted() call, the key= parameter expects a function that will return a value to sort on (in place of the actual values being sorted).

```
logo = sorted(all_freq.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

is equivalent to:

```
def makeSortKey(x):
    return (-x[1],x[0])

logo = sorted(all_freq.items(), key=makeSortKey)
```

the value being returned by the lambda function assumes that the items to be sorted are two-value tuples (or lists) where the second one (a numeric value) is to be use as the main sorting criteria and in descending order (by negating the number).  The first value of the tuple is then used as a secondary sort criteria in ascending order (for identical value of x[1]).  In this case the items of the all_freq dictionary are sorted in descending order of value and ascending order of key where values are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Alain! The concept of simply negating the value to achieve descending order totally escaped me. Now I can see what is happening in the two different solutions, and why mine works for some, but not all.